# How to capture http request in body data - JMeter

Tags: jmeter

We are trying to capture the Id & TwilioSID which is only passed to the body data as a POST. These are dynamic. There is no response data containing these data where generally we use regular expression to retrieve them.

[Id & TwilioSID from recording](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzXKX.png)
Have tried Json extractor on the HTTP request to but no luck.

[Body Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OcnXA.png)
Is there a method to retrieve these data from the Request POST?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If they are in the **request** - you don't need to "capture" them, you can substitute them with [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) so later on you could [parameterize the parameters](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-parameterization-the-complete-guide) using i.e. [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) so each virtual user on each iteration will get different IDs from the .csv file.